# C++ help : how do I stop a while loop and cout the sum?

Tags: c++, while-loop, calculator

I try to build a simple C++ program. A interactive calculator, console based. I have a problem with the `while` loop. It does the code inside the body but not in a specific order to look ok on console.

I tried to place the `sum = sum + num` outside the while but is wrong. I tried many things and this doesn't work.

```
int add , sum = 0 ;

while(add==1 && num!=0){

    cout << "Enter a number , when you are done please type in 0 : ";
    cin >> num;
    numbersEntered++;
    if (num!=0){
     //the problem kind of begins here
        sum = sum + num;
        cout<<" Your total is : " <<sum<<endl;
```

The output is like:

```
Enter a number , when you are done please type in 0 : 5
Your total is : 5
Enter a number , when you are done please type in 0 : 4
Your total is : 9.
```

I type 5 and 4 in this example. To be clear i don't expect this output.

Comment: You didn't type in `0`, so why would it stop?

Comment: What were you expecting ? This seems to work well

Comment: could you provide the end of your algorithm (open braces are not closed, may be is there something else?)

Comment: by the way, you start with `add==1` but `add` is not initialised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to print the sum only at the end, this should work. Just take it out of the while loop. It will stop only when a `0` is entered.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int add = 1, sum = 0, numbersEntered = 0, num = 1;
    while(add==1 && num!=0) {
        cout << "Enter a number, when you are done please type in 0: ";
        cin >> num;
        numbersEntered++;
        sum = sum + num;
    }
    cout << "Your total is: " << sum << endl;
}
```

The `if` condition to check if `num` is not 0 can be removed since `sum + 0` is the same as not adding to `sum`.

Comment: Warning: `add` is initialized but not used (`numbersEntered` as well) ;). Other minor things to improve: drop `using namespace std;`, and consider removing the `if` (hint: what does `sum + 0` equal to?)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm assuming they intend to include other operations which would make it actually useful. If this is the entire program, it's just a constant and not necessary as well as `numbersEntered`.